# Is this a correct knockout ViewModel setup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

This is my first time using knockout. I'm reading/writing a JSON file with a fair bit of nested data. I had no problem creating the ViewModel to just write to the file, but now that I'm reading the data into my model also, I've had to write a few if/else statements to handle the different cases. Not sure if this is the right way to do it.

I've got a ViewModel with a function to add a new record, and to save the data. The 3 functions above are used for mapping the data.

```
function Survey(name, panes, tester) 
{
  this.name = ko.observable(name);
  this.panes = ko.observableArray([new Pane(panes)]);
  this.tester = ko.observable(tester);
}

function Pane(panes) 
{
  //var panesCount = panes.length;
  //console.log(panes[0].type);
  if (panes) {
    this.type = ko.observable(panes[0].type);
    this.head = ko.observable(panes[0].head);
    this.content = ko.observable(panes[0].content);
    this.options = ko.observableArray([new PaneOptions(panes[0].options)]);
  }
  else {
    this.type = ko.observable();
    this.head = ko.observable();
    this.content = ko.observable();
    this.options = ko.observableArray([new PaneOptions()]);
  }
}

function PaneOptions(options) 
{
  //console.log(options);
  if (options) {
    this.data = ko.observable(options[0].data);
    this.target = ko.observable(options[0].target);
  }
  else {
    this.data = ko.observable();
    this.target = ko.observable();
  }
}


function SurveyViewModel()
{
  var self = this;
  self.surveys = ko.observableArray([]);


  $.getJSON("create/fetch", function(data) { 
    //console.log(data.surveys[0].name);
    if (data) { // check if json file is empty
      for (var i=0; i < data.surveys.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        self.surveys.push(new Survey(data.surveys[i].name, data.surveys[i].panes, data.surveys[i].tester))
      }
    }
  });    

  self.addSurvey = function () 
  {
    self.surveys.push(new Survey());
  };

  self.saveUserData = function() 
  { 
    var data_to_send = ko.toJSON(self); 
    $.post("create/save", data_to_send, function(data) { 
      console.log("Your data has been posted to the server!"); 
    }); 
  }

}

var vm = new SurveyViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Here you can see the JSON representation:

```
{
    "surveys": [
        {
            "name": "My First Survey1",
            "panes": [
                {
                    "type": "question1",
                    "head": "Heading Text1",
                    "content": "multichoice1",
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "data": "Time",
                            "target": 2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "tester": "default"
        },
        {
            "name": "My Second Survey2",
            "panes": [
                {
                    "type": "response2",
                    "head": "Heading Text2",
                    "content": "multichoice2",
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "data": "Time",
                            "target": 2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "tester": "default2"
        },
        {
            "name": "My Third Survey3",
            "panes": [
                {
                    "type": "thanks3",
                    "head": "Heading Text3",
                    "content": "multichoice3",
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "data": "Time",
                            "target": 2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "tester": "default3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Overall, it looks really good and serves as a pretty great model of what Knockout models *should* look like, but, internally there are some strange things here like arrays that you are using `[0]` only on (this could be the result of poor data format via your backend web services) and some ambiguity between Panes, Pane, and PaneOptions.

#### (1) Use the guard or ternary operator to create defaults

This will help you avoid some of these logic blocks in all of your constructors.

#### (2) Fix ambiguity with singular and plural constructors (Planes, Plane)

The relationship between Panes and Pane are a little strange! In the `Survey` constructor, you are create a variable called panes (`this.panes`) and then instantiating and passing a new Pane to which you are passing an array of panes? A little bit recursive. In the `Pane` constructor I would not expect to take in panes in the arguments. I think your intention is for the `Survey` to create an array of panes, like this:

```
function Survey(name, panes, tester) 
{
  var _this = this;

  // 1
  this.name = ko.observable(name || '');
  // 2
  this.panes = ko.observableArray();
  this.tester = ko.observable(tester);

  if(panes){
    panes.forEach(function(pane){
      _this.panes.push(new Pane(pane));
    });
  }
}
```

#### (3) Fix improper use of arrays with fixed [0] element

Why is Panes plural in the Pane constructor, if you are only using array item 0? I think the `Pane` constructor should just take in an parameter like `options` which would be used to return an individual pane:

```
function Pane(config) 
{
  this.type = ko.observable(config.type);
  this.head = ko.observable(config.head);
  this.content = ko.observable(config.content);
  this.options = ko.observableArray([new PaneOptions(config.options)]);

  /*
   * You could return "this" but in JS that is the default behavior.
   */
}
```

Additionally, this will help you avoid JS errors when you might attempt to access a null array. For example, if `panes` in `panes[0].options` were `null`, you would have an error at `pane[0]` before you even got to the options property.

I am not sure why you are operating on `options[0]` here - at the point when you are instantiating a Pane, you should be passing in a config (see above) which has an options property, which will most likely be an object like `{ data: "", target: "" }` since that is what you are expecting in the `PaneOptions` constructor:

```
function PaneOptions(options) 
{
  // Setup defaults with ternary operator
  this.data = ko.observable(options ? options.data : '');
  this.target = ko.observable(options ? options.target : '');
}
```

Applicable original code with numbered callouts corresponding to items above

```
function Survey(name, panes, tester) 
{
  // 1
  this.name = ko.observable(name || '');
  // 2
  this.panes = ko.observableArray([new Pane(panes)]);
  this.tester = ko.observable(tester);
}

// 2
function Pane(panes) 
{
  if (panes) {
    // 3
    this.type = ko.observable(panes[0].type);
    this.head = ko.observable(panes[0].head);
    this.content = ko.observable(panes[0].content);
    this.options = ko.observableArray([new PaneOptions(panes[0].options)]);
  }
  else {
    this.type = ko.observable();
    this.head = ko.observable();
    this.content = ko.observable();
    this.options = ko.observableArray([new PaneOptions()]);
  }
}

function PaneOptions(options) 
{
  if (options) {
    // 3
    this.data = ko.observable(options[0].data);
    this.target = ko.observable(options[0].target);
  }
  else {
    this.data = ko.observable();
    this.target = ko.observable();
  }
}
```